# Where are these ads on my lock-screen coming from and how can I get rid of it?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation

Every time when I am close to an "dm market" (a German drugstore) I am getting this advertisement on my lock-screen. When I open this notification it looks like in the second screenshot below. There is no app for "dm" or the related service "PAYBACK" installed on my phone. I used the app in the past but it is no longer on my device.

First of all I would like to understand where is this coming from? And second how can I disable this kind of stuff?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just experienced the same thing, although with a different coupon and app. For me, it turns out that it is coming from the 'Wallet' app. If it is, go to the 'Wallet' app, click on the coupon, then the 'i' on the bottom left. You can select 'Remove Pass' and that should get rid of it.

Comment: Interesting. I had such a coupon in my Wallet app, too. Removed it, and I will test it tomorrow as soon as possible. I will give you feedback.